# Почему phpStorm не распознает User_model.php как php файл?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Проблема конечно мелкая но он раздражает.

В общем в phpStorm последней версии(2018), так было и в версии 2017 в проекте у меня есть файл с названием User_model.php и вот phpSorm не распознает его как php файл, а распознает как простой текстовый файл.

Но так было не всегда. Буквально недавно заметил.

Я понял, что проблема именно в названии файла (User_model.php). Потому что как только поменяю названия файла (например Users_model.php) то файл сразу распознается как php файл.

Это (User_model.php) какая-то зарезервированное имя и его нельзя использовать?

P.S. Я не поставил пометку "Mark as Plain Text".

P.S.S. Такая проблема присутствует во всех проектах в моем phpStorm

Comment: а в начале файле есть тег `<?php`?

Comment: @korytoff Да, есть.

Comment: Проверил, таких проблем нет, может что-то у вас в настройках

Comment: @korytoff Всё, нашли решения. Посмотрите в ответах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зайдите в Settings -> Editor -> File Types
И смотрите там.
В первую очередь посмотрите тип Text
Возможно вы добавили туда этот файлик, и он теперь будет везде в plaintext =)

Comment: Аж смешно, как я умудрился такого сделать)) В общем помогло, спасибо

Comment: Я один раз так тоже так сделал, там видать есть какая то комбинация горячих клавиш, при котором файл туда добавляется)))

Comment: Да, скорее всего так и есть)